# How do I shorten this PHP code to be more general?

Tags: php, optimization

For the PHP masters who read this, I'm sure you'll understand what I'm looking for here. I'm looking for a general way to do what I'm already doing. Currently, I support a method value that has up to 6 method names separated by a | character. If I wanted to be able to support n methods where n could be any number, how could I convert the code below. I'm basically looking for syntax that will help decrease the amount of code I currently have.

```
// example value for $method 
// $method = 'getProjectObject|getProgramObject|getName';

$methods = explode('|', $method);
if (sizeof($methods) == 1) {
    $value = $object->$method();
}
else if (sizeof($methods) == 2) {
    $value = $object->$methods[0]()->$methods[1]();
}
else if (sizeof($methods) == 3) {
    $value = $object->$methods[0]()->$methods[1]()->$methods[2]();
}
else if (sizeof($methods) == 4) {
    $value = $object->$methods[0]()->$methods[1]()->$methods[2]()->$methods[3]();
}
else if (sizeof($methods) == 5) {
    $value = $object->$methods[0]()->$methods[1]()->$methods[2]()->$methods[3]()->$methods[4]();
}
else if (sizeof($methods) == 6) {
    $value = $object->$methods[0]()->$methods[1]()->$methods[2]()->$methods[3]()->$methods[4]()->$methods[5]();
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: Use a for loop. `for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($methods); $i++){/*code*/}`

Comment: that is just far too hideous... the best way to simplify it is to scrap this entirely and start from scratch at the cocktail napkin stage.

Comment: Although the answers below are fine for your purpose, I would like to point out that a lot of conditions (ifelse's) is usually a sign that you need to use a `switch(){}` instead. Of course, in your case the code is way too repetitive making loops a better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$methods = explode('|', $method);
$ret = $object;
foreach ($methods as $method)
{
    $ret = $ret->$method();
}
return $ret;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use some loop like `foreach`:

```
$methods = explode('|', $method);
foreach ($methods as $method) {
    $object = $object->$method();
}
$value = $object;
```